# "What a good news" vs. "such a good news"

Tags: word-choice

I have just got a great news. I don't know what to say:

> Such a good news.

or

> What a good news.

The context should be formal (I am talking about hiring).

Comment: sorry it was my first question, why downvote?

Comment: The downvotes are probably due to the fact that *both* versions are ungrammatical. You might be interested in our proposed sister site for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). You can support it by committing. Thank you.

Comment: ok! i am an English language learner : ) good job!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either work if you remove the "a".
"News" is not countable.

---

The above is correct, and was the selected answer.

However, I wanted to add some clarity.

"Such good news" is a phrase.  "What good news" is an exclamation.

As an exclamation, "**Such good news**!" implies "That is **such good news**!" but you can also say things like, "Where did you hear **such good news**?" or "You always have **such good news**."

"**What good news**!" stands on its own as a full sentence.

Answer (score 1):

"I have just had some good news. It is X...Y...Z."
"What good news!"

Comment: ok, thanks. why "such a" is wrong?

Comment: You can get **a message** or **some messages** or **2, 3, 4... messages**. Message is a count-noun.    You _can't_ get **a measles** or **some measles** or **2, 3 ...measles** - you can only _get measles_. Measles is non-count and, further, non-quantifiable. You _can_ get **news**, **some news / rice** or **not much news / rice** - news and rice are non-count (quasi-non-count for the rice if in grains) but quantifiable.