# About the word "news"

Tags: grammatical-number, syntactic-analysis

From what I read online "news" is treated as a singular noun; however, in this sentence I feel that something is wrong but I am not quite sure:

> 1.) I've got an interesting news to share with you.

Or should it be:

> 2.) I've got some interesting news to share with you.

Comment: Used in that context it is plural and option 2 is idiomatic. It is a word which, as a noun, will not take the indefinite article. However used in a slightly different sense with the definite article it becomes singular "The news is good - he has been rescued".

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92668/what-a-good-news-vs-such-a-good-news

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4146/the-news-is-good-why

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33297/news-singular-or-plural

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example 1) is simply wrong, in British English at least and I think AmE too.

Example 2) is correct, but it's neither "a singular noun", nor "plural", nor "idiomatic".

"news" is an uncountable/mass noun, like butter, water, salt etc. So, it's never used with "a" (except if modified with a singular noun, eg "a news story / source / provider" etc; like "a butter dish", "a water jug" etc). I remember many foreign students of English making that mistake in my teaching days, largely because of it being a countable noun in their languages.

Like other uncountable/mass nouns, we can use "some/any/no + news", and also "a piece/bit etc of news".

"The news" can refer to news programmes / reports generally, eg 
"Have you seen the news today?" (ie any tv / press etc presentation of current events)

And "the news" can also refer to a particular key news story that is reported in the media, or any personally important new occurrence:
"Have you heard the news? The prime minister lied about Grenfell! / Suzie's going to have a baby!"

Answer (score 0):

News is the aggregate of all the reports of the day; therefore it's uncountable, singular.

Merriam-Webster (online) describes the word as “noun plural but singular in construction.” So it takes verbs in singular form: Is there any news?

Politics? Nov 5, 2012
Singular or plural? |

[English for Journalists](https://englishforjournalists.journalism.cuny.edu/2012/11/.../singular.../comment-page-1/)

In the singular, I would offer to share "a piece of" news, a news "story," news "piece," a "bit of" news, or perhaps even a news "bite."